# Sorting in descending order on cost of each Burger which is an ArrayList with Collections.sort

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, collections, compiler-errors

I am trying to sort the burger orders which is in an ArrayList by descending order on cost of each burger. The Burger orders are read in from a textfile with the fields: size, bun, and toppings(String array) based on the size, and toppings I also have another method called burgerCost which calculates the cost of each burger. From my research, it seems the best way is to implement using Collections.sort. However, I am receiving several errors such as:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Pizza 
cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable java.util.Collections$ReverseComparator.compare(Collections.java:5108)
at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:351)
at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:216)
at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1512)
at java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1454)
at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:175)
```

I used the following code below to sort the ArrayList:

```
public void sortBurger() {
    Collections.sort(burger, Collections.reverseOrder());
} // method
```

Comment: `Pizza` doesn't implement `Comparable`, so `Collections` doesn't know how to compare it

Comment: Are we talking about pizzas or burgers here?

Comment: Are you using raw types? Otherwise the compiler should complain instead of compiling and crashing at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

You have to implement your own Comparator class that will do the comparison correctly. Use it as the second parameter.

> public static  void sort(List list,Comparator c)